# What aircraft are parked in this naval air station?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, us-navy

In May 2020 I saw C-130 Hercules on a naval air station in Ventura County, California. Later, I decided to use Apple Maps so that I will remember what I have seen.

Apple Maps showed some C-130 Hercules, F-18 Hornets, P-3 Orions, and a few other aircraft. But when I zoomed into one of the air stations, I noticed some strange aircraft parked next to the P-3 Orions. They appear to be either a foreign aircraft, or some kind of experimental aircraft that I do not know.

[image]

Six of the unknown aircraft have a large swept wing, while two others have a delta wing featuring what looks like a canard.

Comment: It’s possible that these are adversarial aircraft from Draken. Not sure if the Navy has a contract with them or if they would be based out of point Mugu. You can see their inventory here http://www.drakenintl.com/catalog/aircraft-inventory

Comment: How come those are P3 Orions ?

Comment: @adityaguharoy You can identify the P3 Orion by the distinctive MAD (Magnetic Anomaly Detector) boom at the very rear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are private aircraft owned by ATAC for adversary training

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airborne_Tactical_Advantage_Company

> Its main air operations base is at Naval Air Station Point Mugu, California

> It operates Mk-58 Hawker Hunter, Israeli F-21 Kfir, A-4 Skyhawk, and L-39 Albatros II military aircraft in tactical flight training roles for the U.S. Navy, Air Force, and Air National Guard

Comment: Agreed. Hawker Hunters, owned by ATAC. On google maps, if you zoom into the Newport News/Williamsburg airport (PHF), you can see another 3 next to their hangar facility.

Answer (score 23):

At the right end of the row of eight fighters, the two delta wings look like Dassault Mirages.  Trailing edge with a slight reverse sweep.  Ordnance just visible mid-span.  Upper fuselage flared towards the engine inlets.

The six fighters at left look very much like Hawker Hunters, but those are now flown only at air shows.  That guess led me to discover that they *were* stationed at [Point Mugu AFB](https://www.cnic.navy.mil/regions/cnrsw/installations/navbase_ventura_county.html) for a 2015 air show.

A [video](https://youtu.be/GI0qbRtSiGw?t=59) of the maybe-Hunter taxiing at Point Mugu in 2015 also
shows that one of the delta wings has registration N401AX,
which identifies it as a 1980 variant of the Dassault Mirage 5,
an [**Israel Aircraft Industries KFIR-C2**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAI_Kfir).

[Later](https://youtu.be/GI0qbRtSiGw?t=88), the video also shows the maybe-Hunter's registration, N330AX, confirming it as a **1959 Hawker Hunter Mk.58**.

Comment: Right, a Mirage with a canard is a IAI Kfir. +1